# How do i store numbers bigger than 10 billion

Tags: java, variables, int, long-integer

I am making a program and i need a way to make variables go over 10 billion and int only stores up to 999 million for me so i decided to use a long instead of a int and it turn out it only stores up to 999 million as well.

```
int TotalWorldPop = 7200000000;
```

gives me the "literal is out of range" error

```
long TotalWorldPop = 7200000000;
```

gives me the "literal is out of range" error as well

but

```
int TotalWorldPop = 999999999
```

is ok for me

Comment: `int` doesn't only store up to 999 million.  Neither does `long`.  Show your code, please.

Comment: _"int only stores up to 999 million"_ What? Use `BigInteger` for big numbers.

Comment: `long TotalWorldPop = 7200000000L;`

Comment: @assylias There was no code in the original post, so we couldn't guess what numbers the OP wanted to store, he just said _"i need a way to make variables go over 10 billion"_ without any precision about the upper bound. But yes, now we see the code, `long` is enough here.

Comment: I didn't see that original version - my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `long` can accommodate numbers as large as 2<sup>63</sup>-1.  But there's a trick to putting them into the primitive field.

If you're entering the primitive literal, then you have to add an `L` at the end, as [all numeric literals are treated as `int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) (and it can only go up to ~2.1 billion).

If you need numbers larger than *that*, use `BigInteger`.

Comment: ok thanks i didnt know i had to put L at the end of a long, guess i pay the price for being new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to store *very* large numbers.

Example:

```
Biginteger bigInt1 = new Biginteger("91826581752671985235272769716");
Biginteger bigInt2 = new Biginteger("-1796357891266373473772242");
Biginteger bigint3 = bigInt1.divide(bigInt2);
Biginteger bigint4 = bigInt1.add(bigInt2);
```